# How to find out which window triggered WM_PARENTNOTIFY?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, frontend

When I set the parent of a button (A) to another button (B), I found that it won't trigger the `WM_COMMAND` message of button A, and that there will be a `WM_PARENTNOTIFY` message received by the window (parent of button A). But after looking up the reference, I found no way to get the identity of button B, like `HMENU` or `HWND`. Could someone help me?

[image]

[image: Corresponding Image]

Comment: Are you trying to know when the button is clicked on? Don't use WM_PARENTNOTIFY for that.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do here? Are you aware that it is normal for these messages to be sent to the parent of the control? This behaviour is of course documented.

Comment: Why are you putting a button inside a button? That will run into all sorts off problems. For example, keyboard access will be messed up. (The answer to the question is that button B will send its WM_COMMAND to window A. Subclass window A to get it.)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thanks a lot for taking a look at the question and giving answer. May I still ask about that can I get information about button B like HMENU and HWND in this way?

Comment: The sender is implied: If you are handling `WM_COMMAND` in your subclassed button A, it originated from button B. If you are handling `WM_COMMAND` in the parent of button A, you know that it came from button A.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understood what the sender really mean after reading your comment. @IInspectable

Comment: It seems you have solved the question. You can post an answer and mark it, so that other community members can beneift from this thread in the future.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT Thanks for the reminder! I've proposed my solution and please  check if there's anything to be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's sure that it seems strange that somebody put a button into another button, or say set the parent of a button to another button, but it do has some realistic meaning when the parent button has a style of `BS_GROUPBOX`, just as the `Frame` in Visual Basic.

[img_button_in_button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgx0e.png)

My solution to this problem is calling `SetWindowSubClass` after created a new control and so that the new callback function set in calling this API can receive the real hWnd of the control triggering this event.

Something to remark:

- Use `return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);` if that event is not to be handled by the control.
- Remove `WS_CHILD` style for those controls calling `SetWindowSubClass`, or those controls can not be correctly displayed and the only thing displayed would be just an empty window.

Thanks for all who helped me in this question!